# Is there a piecewise-UTM coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, utm, mgrs, dggs

Is there an EPSG code, WKT or a `proj4` string, for a single global piecewise-UTM coordinate system such as MGRS (the NATO military grid reference system)?

I suppose this would work similar to the [HEALpix](https://proj.org/operations/projections/healpix.html) projection?

[image]

Comment: MGRS isn't a coordinate system per se, it still uses the standard WGS84 UTM zones, the grid id as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Grid_Reference_System states *The first part of an MGRS coordinate is the grid-zone designation.* so the first portion tells you what UTM zone you're in then the 2nd part identifies how far north or south you are from the equator then further identifiers improve the definition for more precise locations.